# Highcharts Animation

Tags: animation, highcharts

Is there anyway to animate each and every bubble in bubble charts one by one, from left to right and the size of the bubbles will initially be either smaller or larger and then it should grow to the actual size. Any ideas to proceed further with this requirement is highly appreciated.

/**
 * A Highcharts plugin to display the tooltip in a separate container outside the chart's
 * bounding box, so that it can utilize all space available in the page.
 */

```
(function(H) {
    H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'getLabel', function(proceed) {

        var chart = this.chart,
            options = this.options,
            chartRenderer = chart.renderer,
            box;

        if (!this.label) {

            this.renderer = new H.Renderer(document.body, 400, 500);
            box = this.renderer.boxWrapper;
            box.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top: '-9999px'
            });
            chart.renderer = this.renderer;
            proceed.call(this, chart, options);
            chart.renderer = chartRenderer;

            this.label.attr({
                x: 0,
                y: 0
            });
            this.label.xSetter = function(value) {
                box.element.style.left = value + 'px';
            };
            this.label.ySetter = function(value) {
                box.element.style.top = value + 'px';
            };
        }
        return this.label;
    });

    H.wrap(H.Tooltip.prototype, 'getPosition', function(proceed, boxWidth, boxHeight, point) {
        var chart = this.chart,
            chartWidth = chart.chartWidth,
            chartHeight = chart.chartHeight,
            pos;
        point.plotX += this.chart.pointer.chartPosition.left;
        point.plotY += this.chart.pointer.chartPosition.top;

        // Temporary set the chart size to the full document, so that the tooltip positioner picks it up
        chart.chartWidth = $(document).width();
        chart.chartHeight = $(document).height();

        // Compute the tooltip position
        pos = proceed.call(this, boxWidth, boxHeight, point);

        // Reset chart size
        chart.chartWidth = chartWidth;
        chart.chartHeight = chartHeight;

        return pos;
    });

    /**
     * Find the new position and perform the move. This override is identical
     * to the core function, except the anchorX and anchorY arguments to move().
     */
    H.Tooltip.prototype.updatePosition = function(point) {
        var chart = this.chart,
            label = this.label,
            pos = (this.options.positioner || this.getPosition).call(
                this,
                label.width,
                label.height,
                point
            );

        // do the move
        this.move(
            Math.round(pos.x),
            Math.round(pos.y || 0), // can be undefined (#3977)
            point.plotX + chart.plotLeft - pos.x,
            point.plotY + chart.plotTop - pos.y
        );
    };

}(Highcharts));

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        height: 500,
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'pie'
    },



    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<div class="MyChartTooltip">test<br /> test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br /> test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />  test<br />    </div>';
        }
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]

});
```

Comment: Any ideas on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add point with small z values and then update them one by one asynchronously (after the one point is updated, update the next one)

You can also override `bubble.prototype.animate` function and change default animation-like this:

```
Highcharts.seriesTypes.bubble.prototype.animate = function(init) {
  var H = Highcharts
  var each = H.each
  var animation = this.options.animation;
  var points = this.points
  var animatePoint = i => {
    var point = points[i]
    var graphic = point && point.graphic
    var animationTarget

    if (graphic && graphic.width) {
      animationTarget = {
        x: graphic.targetX,
        y: graphic.targetY,
        width: graphic.targetWidth,
        height: graphic.targetHeight
      }

      graphic.animate(animationTarget, animation, () => {
        animatePoint(i + 1)
      });
    } else {
      this.update({ dataLabels: { enabled: true }})
    }
  }

  if (!init) { // run the animation


    each(points, function(point) {
      var graphic = point.graphic,
        animationTarget;

      if (graphic && graphic.width) { // URL symbols don't have width
        graphic.targetWidth = graphic.width
        graphic.targetHeight = graphic.height
        graphic.targetX = graphic.x
        graphic.targetY = graphic.y
          // Start values
        graphic.attr({
          x: point.plotX,
          y: point.plotY,
          width: 1,
          height: 1
        });
      }
    });

    animatePoint(0)

    // delete this function to allow it only once
    this.animate = null;
  }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/hpk497hb/

Comment: You can split the animation into two steps - the first step for moving bubbles from left to right and then increasing their size http://jsfiddle.net/hpk497hb/2/

Comment: Yes, you should create a new question with the code/demo - to show what you have already done.